# Why golang yaml head comment becomes foot comment after unmarshal

Tags: go, yaml

I am testing with `HeadComment` from a very simple code below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type Person struct {
    Name *yaml.Node
}

func main() {
    nameNode := &yaml.Node{
        Kind:        yaml.ScalarNode,
        HeadComment: "The name of a person",
        Value:       "Lily",
        Style: yaml.DoubleQuotedStyle,
    }

    person := Person{
        Name: nameNode,
    }

    dataInBytes, _ := yaml.Marshal(person)
    fmt.Println(string(dataInBytes))
}
```

I am expecting to see the output like this:

```
# The name of a person
name: "Lily"
```

However, I got:

```
name: "Lily"
# The name of a person
```

A head comment becomes a foot comment. Anyone has ideas ? Thanks !

https://play.golang.org/p/10bQt2KTKBU

Comment: Opened an issue against golang yaml: https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/issues/610

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because that head comment is attached to the value node (not `name:`, but `"Lily"`) in YAML document tree.

So when events are being emitted that comment in fact belongs:

```
name: "Lily"
     ^-- here
```

It kinda makes sense that `go-yaml` puts header comment for value at the end of pair. Rather than expected behavior I'd call that implementation, so it's good that you've already opened a ticket with author of library to see whether they want to change implementation and move the head comment of `value` in `key: value` pair to position of header comment of `key` instead (I agree, specially in case when used to marshal struct this makes sense and is more handy).

Here is an example of code that creates same structure and adds head comment to `name:` key instead to get proper rendering (at cost of losing nice struct):

```golang
func main() {
        key := &yaml.Node{
                Kind:        yaml.ScalarNode,
                Value:       "name",
                HeadComment: "The name of a person",
        }
        value := &yaml.Node{
                Kind:  yaml.ScalarNode,
                Value: "Lilly",
                Style: yaml.DoubleQuotedStyle,
        }

        mapping := &yaml.Node{
                Kind:    yaml.MappingNode,
                Content: []*yaml.Node{key, value},
        }

        dataInBytes, _ := yaml.Marshal(mapping)
        fmt.Println(string(dataInBytes))
}
```

Output:

```
# The name of a person
name: "Lilly"
```